# JS: Create function that returns function that, when invoked waits for the specified amount of time before executing

Tags: javascript, function, callback, set, timeout

My objective is to:

Write a function delay that accepts two arguments, a callback and the wait time in milliseconds. Delay should return a function that, when invoked waits for the specified amount of time before executing. HINT - research setTimeout();

I tried the code below:

```
const delay = (inputFunc, waitTime, ...args) => { 

  return function () {
    return setTimeout(inputFunc(), waitTime, ...args)
  }
}

// UNCOMMENT THE CODE BELOW TO TEST DELAY
let count = 0;

const delayedFunc = delay(() => count++, 1000);
delayedFunc();

console.log(count);                                                  // should print '0'

setTimeout(() => console.log(count), 1000); // should print '1' after 1 second
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function at setTimeout (timers.js:390:11)
```

What am I doing wrong?  What should the answer be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> setTimeout(inputFunc(), waitTime, ...args)

This means "immediately call inputFunc(), then pass its result in as the first parameter to setTimeout (along with waitTime and args)". Instead you want:

```
setTimeout(inputFunc, waitTime, ...args)
```

Another option, particularly if you need to do extra things when the timeout goes off, is to create an additional function, and that function will call inputFunc. For example:

```
setTimeout(() => { 
  // do some cleanup stuff related to delay
  inputFunc();
}, waitTime, ...args);
```

Comment: oh wow, so the parenthesis after inputFunc make all the difference?

Comment: Yes. If you just want that function to be called when the timeout goes off, then you pass in a reference to the function and setTimeout will call it for you at the appropriate time. You don't call it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
function delay(callback, waitTime, ...args) {
  
  return function () {
    return setTimeout(callback, waitTime, ...args)  

  }
}
```

Basically had it just don't need those () on the callback